# What is the best practice for detecting touch capability (tablet PC) in a Delphi app for Windows?

Tags: delphi, touch

My app runs on a desktop PC and / or a tablet PC. For the latter though, I see that I have to provide an on-screen keyboard - this is not hard with the supplied TTouchKeyboard. My question is how to find out whether touch is available or not? I have found [some sample code](http://delphi.longzu.net/viewthread.php?tid=46731&extra=page=144) which makes WinAPi calls to GetSystemMetrics:

```
function GetTouchCapabilities : TTouchCapabilities;
 var ADigitizer : integer;
 begin
 result := [];
 // First check if the system is a TabletPC
 if GetSystemMetrics(SM_TABLETPC) <> 0 then begin
   include(result,tcTabletPC);
   if CheckWin32Version(6,1) then begin // If Windows 7, then we can do additional tests on input type
    ADigitizer := GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH) <> 0) then include(result,tcIntTouch);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_EXTERNAL_TOUCH) <> 0) then include(result,tcExtTouch);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_INTEGRATED_PEN) <> 0) then include(result,tcIntPen);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_EXTERNAL_PEN) <> 0) then include(result,tcExtPen);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_MULTI_INPUT) <> 0) then include(result,tcMultiTouch);
    if ((ADigitizer and NID_READY) <> 0) then include(result,tcReady);
   end else begin
    // If not Windows7 and TabletPC detected, we asume that it's ready
    include(result,tcReady);
   end;
 end;
 end;
```

There is also the [Microsoft definition of a tablet PC here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_getsystemmetrics__sm_tabletpc_).

I then did a search of the RTL and Delphi source to try to locate routines that more directly gave me this information in a similar way to how Delphi wraps the OS version information but I can't see any (although it may be that I just don't know what to search for!). Is the above code style the best way of detecting touch capability? Or am I missing something much more obvious?

Comment: I realise that you're the one having English as your native language, but isn't it 'tablet PCs'?

Comment: Duly noted and corrected :-)

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: `CheckWin32Version()` returns whether the OS version is *at least* the specified version. Windows 7 is 6.1, so `CheckWin32Version(6, 1)` will return true for Windows 7, Windows 8, on so on.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Delphi does not provide a wrapper for reporting Tablet PC capabilities, so what you have shown is what you will need to use in your code.